# getView not called on baseAdapter class

Tags: android, listview, navigation-drawer, baseadapter

i have this class which extends `BaseAdapter` that i use to insert an `icon` and a `textView` for each row of a `listView` that is inside a drawer

```
public class NavRightDrawerListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    LinkedList<String> userNameUsedForListView;
    Map<String, Bitmap> urlUserImage;

    public NavRightDrawerListAdapter(Context context, LinkedList<String> userNameUsedForListView, Map<String, Bitmap> returnBitMapFromURL) {
        this.context = context;
        this.userNameUsedForListView = userNameUsedForListView;
        this.urlUserImage = returnBitMapFromURL;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        int count = 0;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_of_action, null);
        }

        ImageView imgIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);

        imgIcon.setImageBitmap(urlUserImage.get(userNameUsedForListView.get(count)));
        txtTitle.setText(userNameUsedForListView.get(count));
        count++;
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
}
```

and in my activity i do this:

```
[...]
rightDrawerLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.right_drawer_ll);
rightDrawerListForFollow = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.right_drawer);
NavRightDrawerListAdapter adapter = new NavRightDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), userNameUsedForListView,returnBitMapFromURL);
rightDrawerListForFollow.setAdapter(adapter);
[...]
```

i notice that the getView is not being called, someone can explain me why?

thanks a lot.

Comment: I am guessing that since your adapter claims to be empty (getCount returns 0), the ListView does not bother asking for item views

Comment: well, i have to return the size of my lsit used by the adapter? i can't leave it to 0?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your method

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
```

you are returning 0. so your method is not called. Instead return size of your list-view in getCount method.

Comment: thanks for the answer,  , is called getCount firstly right? and the getView?

Comment: yes, your getCount() method is called first and then your getView() is called as many times as you return counter value.

Answer (score 1):

This has already been answered here:

[Custom adapter getview is not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16250292/custom-adapter-getview-is-not-called)

Your getCount method is returning 0, so no need for the adapter to call getView().