# getView of custom ArrayAdapter not being called

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter, custom-adapter

Similar question to 
[Custom adapter getview is not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16250292/custom-adapter-getview-is-not-called)

I have a custom adapter to put images on my app screen but it is not being called at all. Doing some research I found that I needed to override a `getCount()` method. I have done this returning the size of the ArrayList, but still no luck. I thought the list could have been empty, but through debugging, I can confirm it is not when it is passed through to the custom ArrayAdapter class. I even tried returning a value of 20 in `getCount()` to see if that would work, but still no luck.

Here is the code I have done so far;

**MainActivityFragment.class**

```
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {
    private ImageAdapter imageAdapter;

    public class FetchMovieTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject strings) {


            Log.i(LOG_TAG, strings.toString());

            try {
                jsonArray = strings.getJSONArray("results");


            if (null != jsonArray) {

                ArrayList<JSONObject> list = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();

                if (jsonArray != null) {
                    int len = jsonArray.length();
                    for (int i=0;i<len;i++){
                        list.add((JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i));
                    }
                }

                imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(getActivity(), list);
            }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- There is a lot more to this fragment class, but I just included where I return a JSONObject from `doInBackground()` and in `onPostExecute()` I extract a JSONArray from the JSONObject and put each element from the JSONArray into an `ArrayList<JSONObject>` and send that to my custom ArrayAdapter class

**ImageAdapter.class**

```
public class ImageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ArrayList> {

ArrayList list;
Context context;

public ImageAdapter(Context context, ArrayList list) {
    super(context, android.R.id.content);
    this.list = list;
    this.context = context;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    //return list.size();
    return 20;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    String IMAGE_BASE_URL = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/";

    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) list.get(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_image_movie, parent, false);
        }

        ImageView iv = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_movie_pics_imageview);

        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(IMAGE_BASE_URL + jsonObject.get("poster_path"))
                .into(iv);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return convertView;
}

}
```

- getCount has been set to the `list.size()` value, where the list is not null and it is still not called
- It has been hardcoded to 20 (the size of the list) and it is still not called

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: where are you calling setAdapter ? Check if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16338281/custom-adapter-getview-method-is-not-called/16338380#16338380) helps

Comment: I am calling it in the `onCreateView` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After intializing your `Adapter` set it to your `ListView`

```
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

private ImageAdapter imageAdapter;

public class FetchMovieTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject strings) {


        Log.i(LOG_TAG, strings.toString());

        try {
            jsonArray = strings.getJSONArray("results");


        if (null != jsonArray) {

            ArrayList<JSONObject> list = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();

            if (jsonArray != null) {
                int len = jsonArray.length();
                for (int i=0;i<len;i++){
                    list.add((JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i));
                }
            }

            imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(getActivity(), list);
            yourListView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
        }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect :)
I had set the adapter in onCreateView but declared the imageAdapter in onPostExecute. When I moved it down to onPostExecute it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after creating this. This will notify the adapter to call `getView()`

**UPDATE**
Set adapter on listView and then notifyDataSetChanged

`yourListView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);`
`imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment I can see you are assigning your adapter to the `listview` in `onCreateView` method. Your adapter is not ready by then. So you need to refresh your adapter after adding data to it.

Add

```
imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

After

```
imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(getActivity(), list);
```

in `onPostExecute` method.