# getCount() is being called before BaseAdapter constructor method finishes executing

Tags: android, json, android-gridview, baseadapter

I am new to android. I am trying to create a GridView 
consisting of ImageView. The images are from flickr and I am using flickr API to search flickr and receive JSON response. I parse the JSON data to get image URL. The API call and parsing JSON data is done inside FlickrAdapter which extends BaseAdapter. But the problem is my getView() method is never called. I searched [stackoverflow for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16250292/custom-adapter-getview-is-not-called) and I found that if there is no data to show then getView() will not be called. But I am setting the data in FlickrAdapter constructor. I've set some debug texts in the methods and I see that getCount() is called before the data is set which means getCount() is called before the FlickrAdapter constructor finishes executing. So getView() is never called.
I want getCount() method to be called after the constructor method of my FlickrAdapter finishes executing.
How can I solve this problem?

Here is my code for the BaseAdapter and other classes

**FlickrAdapter.java**

```
public class FlickrAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

public ArrayList<FlickrImage> flickrImagesList;
private Context context;

public static  FlickrAdapter instance;
FlickrAdapter(final Context context, String searchText, Activity activity) {
    this.flickrImagesList = new ArrayList<FlickrImage>();
    this.context = context;
    instance = this;
    Flickr flickr = new Flickr(searchText, context, activity);
    //row[0] = inflater.inflate(R.layout.template, null, false);
    Log.d("URL", flickr.buildApiUrl());
    DownloadManager.getJsonResponse(flickr.buildApiUrl(), context, new VolleyCallBack<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(JSONObject success) {
            //Log.d("JSON",success.toString());
            try {
                success = success.getJSONObject("photos");
                JSONArray photo = success.getJSONArray("photo");

                for (int i = 0; i < photo.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject tempObject = photo.getJSONObject(i);
                    String result = new StringBuilder("https://farm" + tempObject.get("farm").toString() +
                            ".staticflickr.com/" +
                            tempObject.get("server").toString() +
                            "/" +
                            tempObject.get("id").toString() +
                            "_" +
                            tempObject.get("secret").toString() +
                            "_n.jpg").toString();

                    FlickrImage image = new FlickrImage(i, result);
                    instance.flickrImagesList.add(image);

                    Log.d("SIZE", String.valueOf(instance.flickrImagesList.size()));

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    Log.d("COUNT",String.valueOf(flickrImagesList.size()));
    return flickrImagesList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return flickrImagesList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

class ViewHolder {
    ImageView myImage;

    ViewHolder(View v) {
        myImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.individulaImage);
    }
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.individual_image, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder(row);
        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }


    FlickrImage tempImage = flickrImagesList.get(position);
    Log.d("Address", tempImage.imageName);

    //ImageView iv = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.individulaImage);

    //Picasso.with(context).load(tempImage.imageName).into(iv);
    return row;
}}
```

**Flickr.java**

```
public class Flickr {
private StringBuilder urlBuilder = new StringBuilder("https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=e78808f6cf756218d6981fcdf8021f0c&tags=");
private String apiUrl = "";
private Context context = null;
private Activity activity;
private String[] individualImageUrl;
private String keyWord = "";

public Flickr(String keyWord, Context context, Activity activity) {
    this.keyWord=keyWord;
    this.apiUrl = buildApiUrl();
    this.context = context;
    this.activity = activity;
    //Log.d("APIURL", this.apiUrl);
}

public String buildApiUrl() {
    String[] temp;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    temp = this.keyWord.split(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
        sb.append(temp[i]);
        if (i != (temp.length - 1)) {
            sb.append("+");
        }
    }
    urlBuilder.append(sb);
    urlBuilder.append("&text=");
    urlBuilder.append(sb);
    urlBuilder.append("&format=json&nojsoncallback=1");

    return urlBuilder.toString();
}}
```

**FlickrImage.java**

```
public class FlickrImage {
public int imageId;
public String imageName;

FlickrImage(int imageId, String imageURL) {
    this.imageId = imageId;
    this.imageName = imageURL;
    }
}
```

**VolleyCallBack.java**

```
public interface VolleyCallBack<T> {
public void onSuccess(T success);
}
```

**DownloadManager.java**

```
public class DownloadManager {
public static void getJsonResponse(final String Url, Context context, final VolleyCallBack callBack) {
    JsonObjectRequest flickrJsonRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, Url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    callBack.onSuccess(response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    error.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
    Volley.newRequestQueue(context).add(flickrJsonRequest);
}
}
```

Comment: I've seen some examples where one loads the data by starting an `AsyncTask` (e.g. in `onCreate()` ) and in `onPostExecute()` pushes them into the data list ( your 'flickrImagesList') and calls `notifyDatasetChanged()`, May be worth a try.

Comment: I have some idea on AsyncTask but none on notifyDatasetChanged(). I will have a look and give it a try. Thanks

Comment: @0X0nosugar notifyDatasetChanged() worked perfectly. Thanks a lot man :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not being called before your constructor completes. YOur web code runs in a seperate thread so your constructor code completes and then getCount is called. Once your web code is complete onSuccess is called.

It is never advisable to run network code in adapter. Run it in your activity or fragment and once it completes call notifyDatasetChanged() on your adapter.

Comment: When I search for something, I get the following message in my debug log
  05-10 11:15:54.677 22120-22120/com.example.mamun.wp     D/COUNT: 0

05-10 11:15:54.677 22120-22120/com.example.mamun.wp D/COUNT: 0

05-10 11:15:54.677 22120-22120/com.example.mamun.wp D/COUNT: 0

05-10 11:15:56.507 22120-22120/com.example.mamun.wp D/SIZE: 1

05-10 11:15:56.507 22120-22120/com.example.mamun.wp D/SIZE: 2

Here "COUNT" is printed inside getCount and "SIZE" inside the Adapter constructor.  But by what you have told me "SIZE" should always be printed before "COUNT"

Comment: By what i have told you count will mostly be printed before size and thats your problem.  get count runs before your onSuccess callback

Comment: I got it. I had a debug before the callBack and it printed before count. But I still have no idea how I can make my callBack finish executing before the getCount() is called. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: YOu cant make it finish without hanging your device. I would suggest moving the network code to activity, setting up adapter with empty list and then calling adapter.notifydatasetChanged once your loading is done.

Comment: I'll try that and let you know. Thanks for the help